# Can't seem to match multiple KeyValuePatterns in one pattern

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, associations

Let's define a couple patterns that we can use to match `Association`s.

```
With[{key = {_?NonNegative, _?NonNegative | Infinity}},
  symbolPattern = KeyValuePattern[{(key -> _Symbol) ...}];
  positivePattern = KeyValuePattern[{(key -> _?Positive) ...}]];
```

These work as expected:

```
MatchQ[<|{0, 1} -> a, {1, 3} -> b|>, symbolPattern]
(* True *)

MatchQ[<|{0, 2} -> 1, {2, 4} -> 3|>, positivePattern]
```

They also work as part of a larger pattern:

```
MatchQ[{<|{0, 1} -> a, {1, 3} -> b|>, 3}, {symbolPattern, _Integer}]
(* True *)
```

However, they don't both work as parts of the **same** larger pattern:

```
MatchQ[{<|{0, 1} -> a, {1, 3} -> b|>, <|{0, 2} -> 1, {2, 4} -> 3|>},
 {symbolPattern, positivePattern}]
(* False *)
```

What on Earth is going on?

Comment: Reproduced on my machine (Mac OS X, M 12.1). Looks like a bug.

Comment: There is a much simpler example demonstrating this: `patt = KeyValuePattern[{({_, _} -> _) ...}]; assoc = <|{0, 1} -> 1, {1, 3} -> 2|>; MatchQ[assoc, patt] (* True *); MatchQ[{assoc, assoc}, {patt, patt}] (* False *)`. I have reported this bug.

Comment: This now works in version 13.2 (don't know when the fix actually occurred).